# Problema con componente

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript

tengo un problema con mi proyecto. Estoy haciendo la conexion de mi back con el front y llego a esta parte donde debo declarar el servicio pero me da el error:
*"La propiedad 'PorfolioService' no existe en el tipo 'TableComponent'."*
Alguien me podria explicar porque me figura este error y como solucionarlo?

Este es mi Servicio

```html
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Usuario } from '../model/Usuario';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PorfolioService {

  Usuario:Usuario[];

  constructor( private http:HttpClient) { }

  Url='http://localhost:8080/porfolio/user';

  getUsuario(){
    return this.http.get<Usuario[]>(this.Url);
  }

  obtenerDatos():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('./assets/data/data.json');
  }

}
```

Y este el Componente

```html
import { PorfolioService } from './../../servicies/porfolio.service';
import { Usuario } from './../../model/Usuario';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private http:PorfolioService, private router:Router){}

  usuario:Usuario[];

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.PorfolioService.getUsuario()
    .subscribe(data =>{
      this.usuario=data;
    })

  }

}
```

El error lo marca en PorfolioService
`this.PorfolioService.getUsuario().subscribe(data =>{this.usuario=data;})`

Comment: Lo has declarado como `http` en el constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**PorfolioService** es la clase que has declarado en el servicio, mientras que a lo que quieres acceder es a una instancia de esa clase, que es el http que declaras en el constructor. Por lo tanto, deberías modificar tu expresión para que diga

```
this.http.getUsuario()
```

Si no tienes claro lo que es la inyección de código, puedes seguir mi curso de Angular en Youtube. Lo puedes encontrar en mi perfil.

Answer (score 0):

En el constructor el nombre del *service* debe ser más detallado, por ejemplo;

```
constructor(private portfolioService:PorfolioService, private router:Router){}
```

Eso en caso de que reutilices otros servicios. Para llamar al método del servicio declarado:

```
this.portfolioService.getUsuario()
    .subscribe((data) =>{
      this.usuario=data;
    })
```